# IIS permissions issue pointing docroot to Samba share

Tags: iis-7, samba

I have an IIS project which is stored on a Samba shared, network mounted with the following line:

```
X: \\my-samba-server\dev /user:freddie
```

Connectivity is fine, can read/write files from `X:`.

In IIS, I'm trying to set it as the `Physical path` via `\\my-samba-server\dev\folder\to\my\files`, which results in the following `500.19` error:

`Config Error | Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions`

It is by default trying to use the `Pass-through authentication`. If I try to set this to connect as the specific user `freddie`, I receive:

`The specified user does not exist`

What is the correct way to connect to a path which has been setup as described above?

**Samba man pages indicate version 3.6 is on the Debian host*

Answer (score 0):

OK, the resolution was to add a local user (yes, for connecting to a remote drive that Windows has no trouble mapping to a network drive otherwise).

With the local user named `freddie`, I was able to specify that user name and connect fine.

Referenced from [this thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1153949.aspx).